# How to serialize generic inheritance class types with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, protobuf-net

I've got a rather complex model structure and I'm hoping I can implement the serialization with protobuf-net. I've written a couple of tests and most of them work absolutely fine, but some more complex generic class structures with inheritance on both the class type and the generic type don't work.

In the example below, the models don't have constructors, but I left them out to not overflow the post with information. Please assume that the parameterless constructors are implemented in all models. Also, I'm aware that some property names don't make sense, but it's a simplified prototype for a bigger project.

*note: I know that this model is probably overcomplicated, but unfortunately I'm hugely stuck with it.*

**Models**

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SaveData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<Entity> entities { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class Entity
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(910, typeof(SpecificEvent<SpecificEventArguments, SpecificEventContext>))]
public class Event<T, U> : Entity 
    where T : EventArguments
    where U : EventContext
{
    [ProtoMember(22)]
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(23)]
    public T EventArguments { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(902)]
    public U EventContext { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(30, typeof(SpecificEventArguments))]
public class EventArguments
{
    [ProtoMember(24)]
    public int Argument { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(901, typeof(SpecificEventContext))]
public class EventContext
{
    [ProtoMember(900)]
    public string SomeContext { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SpecificEventArguments : EventArguments
{
    [ProtoMember(25)]
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SpecificEventContext : EventContext
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SpecificEvent<T, U> : Event<T, U>
    where T : SpecificEventArguments
    where U : SpecificEventContext
{
}
```

When I try to write some serialization logic in a simple `main` cmd-script, I can't seem to figure out why the serialization doesn't work.

**Logic**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SaveData saveData = new SaveData();
    SpecificEvent<SpecificEventArguments, SpecificEventContext> specificEvent = 
        new SpecificEvent<SpecificEventArguments, SpecificEventContext>(
            "specific", "event", 
            new SpecificEventArguments(1), 
            new SpecificEventContext());
    saveData.entities.Add(specificEvent);

    using (var file = File.Create("savedata.bin"))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(file, saveData);
    }

    SaveData loaded = null;
    using (var file = File.OpenRead("savedata.bin"))
    {
        loaded = Serializer.Deserialize<SaveData>(file);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unexpected sub-type: protobuf_net_test.Program+SpecificEvent`2[[protobuf_net_test.Program+SpecificEventArguments, protobuf-net-test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[protobuf_net_test.Program+SpecificEventContext, protobuf-net-test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
```

Can anyone please explain me what I'm doing wrong? All help is really appreciated!!

Comment: The *ultimate* cause is the lack of a proto-include on Event`2; not at a PC - have you tried adding that include? Or does the compiler not allow it because of the generic constraint? It can almost certainly be hacked in, especially at runtime via the model callbacks, but: I'm doing the Xmas thing right now - not really coding for a few days (I'm the library author, in case that seemed like unnecessary information!) Also: what library version are you using?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the amazingly quick response, especially in a holiday period. I actually forgot to include (no pun intended) that line, so I've added it in the original post. It still doesn't work and gives me the same error, unfortunately. Oh and the version number is V3.0.73 (latest one)

Comment: K, I'll try and take a look when I'm done with holidays; thanks for the update